# How to show title price and images from php database in android listview

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, android-listview

I want to show title price and images of advertisement from php database in my android application listview. Please help me with  details of code. I have stored title price and image path in php database. I Googled a lot for this but coudnt get perfect result.. I tried picasso also but coudnt use it in listview.  I m new in android so please help me with details...

Thanks in advance

Comment: "php database" - what's that supposed to be? Have you written a db in php? Or do you mean a MySQL database?

Comment: I mean mysql database

Comment: Where is that database? On your device? On the web?

Comment: Are you sure you couldn't find anything by googling . :) https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=android+listview+with+image+and+text

Comment: I found but only title and price i can show with that but not image thats why i ask this question